# Three dimensional matrix, Cartesian product

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have three vectors a, b and c. The value of a_i depends is the sum of the Cartesian product of all the values of the vectors b and c, which again is multiplied by a factor of the three dimensional matrix w:

[image]

How do I write that in Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

Let `b, c` be column vectors. The simplest way is to collapse `w` to a two dimensional matrix, then multiply by `b` as follows:

```
w2 = sum(bsxfun(@times,w,shiftdim(c,-2)),3);
a = w2 * b;
```

Here I test it for random data, for syntax errors:

```
n = 10;
w = randn(n,n,n); 
b = randn(n,1); 
c = randn(n,1);
w2 = sum(bsxfun(@times,w,shiftdim(c,-2)),3);
a = w2 * b;

% using loops:
aalt = zeros(n,1);
for ii=1:n
    for jj=1:n
        for kk=1:n
            aalt(ii,1) = aalt(ii,1) + w(ii,jj,kk) * b(jj) * c(kk);
        end
    end
end
% up to roundoff error:
max(abs(aalt - a))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = sum(sum(bsxfun(@times, w, shiftdim(bsxfun(@times, b(:), c(:).'), -1)), 3), 2)
```

Or replace the inner `bsxfun` by matrix multiplication:

```
a = sum(sum(bsxfun(@times, w, reshape(b(:)*c(:).',[1 numel(b) numel(c)])), 3), 2)
```

Comment: @rayryeng :-) Such a powerful tool